# open syscall on fifo not blocking?

Tags: c, unix, fifo

I'm creating a quite-big project as an homework where I need to create a server program which listen to 2 fifos, where clients will write.

Everything works, but there is something that is making me angry: whenever I do an operation, which is composed from some write/reads between client and server, when I close fifos on client, it looks like server "think" that there is still someone keeping those fifos opened.

Due to this, the server tries to read 64 byte after each operation, obviusly failing (reading 0 bytes). **Only one time per operation this thing happens, it doesn't keep trying to read 64 byte**

It doesn't create any problem to clients but it's really strange and I hate those type of bugs

I think it's a problem connected to open/close and to the fact that clients use a lock.

*Note, flags used on the open operation are specified in this pseudocode text*

Server behaviour:

```
Open Fifo(1) for READING (O_RDONLY)
Open Fifo(2) for WRITING (O_WRONLY)
Do some operations
Close Fifo(1)
Close Fifo(2)
```

Client behaviour:

```
Set a lock on Fifo(1) (waiting if there is already one)
Set a lock on Fifo(2) (same as before)
Open Fifo(1) for WRITING (O_WRONLY)
Open Fifo(2) for READING (O_RDONLY)
Do some operations
Close Fifo(1)
Close Fifo(2)
Get lock from Fifo(1)
Get lock from Fifo(2)
```

I can't post directly the code, except from the functions used for networking because the project is quite big and I don't use syscalls directly. Here you are:

```
int Network_Open(const char* path,int oflag)
{
    return open(path,oflag);
}

ssize_t Network_IO(int fifo,NetworkOpCodes opcode,void* data,size_t dataSize)
{
    ssize_t retsize = 0;
    errno = 0;

    if (dataSize == 0) return 0;

    while ((retsize = (opcode == NetworkOpCode_Write? write(fifo,data,dataSize) : read(fifo,data,dataSize))) < 0)
    {
        if (errno != EINTR) break;
    }

    return retsize;
}

Boolean Network_Send(int fifo,const void* data,size_t dataSize)
{
    return ((ssize_t)dataSize) == Network_IO(fifo,NetworkOpCode_Write,(void*)data,dataSize);
}

Boolean Network_Receive(int fifo,void* data,size_t dataSize)
{
    return ((ssize_t)dataSize) == Network_IO(fifo,NetworkOpCode_Read,data,dataSize);
}

Boolean Network_Close(int fifo)
{
    if (fifo >= 0)
        return close(fifo) == 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

*Client output:* http://pastie.org/2523854
*Server output (strace):* http://pastie.org/2523858

Comment: What flags are you passing to open in Network_Open?

Comment: O_RDONLY for reading and O_WRONLY for writing, nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero bytes result from `read()` means that the other process has finished.  Now your server must close the original file descriptor and reopen the FIFO to serve the next client.  The blocking operations will resume once you start working with the new file descriptor.

That's the way it is supposed to work.

AFAIK, after you get the zero bytes, further attempts to read on the file descriptor will also return 0 bytes, in perpetuity (or until you close the file descriptor).  Even if another process opens the FIFO, the original file descriptor will continue to indicate EOF (the other client process will be hung waiting for a server process to open the FIFO for reading).

Answer (score 3):

Zero bytes returned from (blocking) read() indicates an end of file, i.e., that the other end has closed the FIFO. Read the manpage for read.

Comment: I can understand this but WHY my server open the first fifo (read) if there is no one on the other end in writing mode?

Comment: Mh yea but I'm opening the descriptor in blocking mode, that's why I don't understand this behaviour

Comment: Well, nothing in the code shows this behavior. If all you do is open the fifo, read some data, and eventually read returns 0, everything is perfectly normal. What do you do when read returns 0 ? Are you telling us you open the fifo again ? Before a client opens it again ? run `strace` on your application to see what happens

Comment: What you wrote is exactly what happened, I open the fifo, do some operations and close it. The client terminate after closing everything. However, the server reopen the fifo and tries to read again, discover that we reached eof, discard packet and close.

Comment: Mh I think the problem doesn't show up with strace because it sends too much output to stdout, slowing program execution and removing the problem (the same thing happens with a lot of printfs)

Comment: The program does not open the fifo by itself, you have programmed it to do so - so show that code (the code that closes the fifo and reopens it) Does your client send a disconnect message ? Are you using fixed length messages (if not, you hopefully handle that a fifo is a byte stream, and not assume it is message based). Are you using multiple readers/writers ? If strace or printfs makes the problem disappear, you have a bug somewhere.